# How to show the content from RichTextArea.getHMTL() in a div properly?

Tags: gwt, xss, richtextarea

If pasting an image into  RichTextArea,then.getHTML(),it will return a escaped html string like this:

```
"&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.example.com/images/n1.png&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; height=&quot;75&quot; width=&quot;199&quot;&gt;"
```

then if

```
div.setInnerHTML(escaped html string),
```

it will be shown as plain html:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/n1.png" border="0" height="75" width="199">
```

not expected result:an image,and other html content has this issue,for example,if inputing this content to RichTextArea:

```
<script>alert("evil xss");</script>
```

then getHTML() will return:

<script>alert("evil xss");</script>

and then div.setInnertHTML(escapted html),it will be shown as

```
&lt;script&gt;alert("evil xss");&lt;/script&gt;
```

not expected content:

```
<script>alert("evil xss");</script>
```

So,how to show them properly?

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML (which is rendered as div) and assign it as SafeHtmlString.

Comment: Thanks,but still,htmWidget.setHTML("&lt;script&gt;alert("Evil XSS!!!!")&lt;/script&gt;") will render content as "&lt;script&gt;alert("Evil XSS!!!!")&lt;/script&gt;",not expected "<script>alert("Evil XSS!!!!")</script>"

Comment: The key is to use SafeHtml

Comment: What do you mean?I have tried:htmWidget.setHTML(SafeHtml fromTrustedString("&lt;script&gt;alert("Evil XSS!!!!")&lt;/script&gt;")),